# Access Token isn't refresh automatically

Tags: oauth-2.0, mule, httprequest, access-token, anypoint-studio

I'm using the OAuth2 Client Credentials Protocol in Mule HTTP Request Config (Mule runtime 3.8.5) and it's my first time setting this up but it doesn't seem to be able to refresh the access token automatically when it is expired (each token lasts for 90 mins) and instead it will return payload with error_description = 'Access Token Expired'. What did I miss?

```
<http:request-config name="HTTPS_Request_Configuration" protocol="HTTPS" host="${API.HOST}" port="${API.PORT}" tlsContext-ref="TLS_Configuration" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" responseTimeout="${RESPONSE.TIMEOUT}">
    <oauth2:client-credentials-grant-type clientId="${TOKEN.API.CLIENT_ID}" clientSecret="${TOKEN.API.CLIENT_SECRET}" tlsContext-ref="TLS_Configuration">
        <oauth2:token-request tokenUrl="https://${API.HOST}${TOKEN.API.PATH}" scopes="Entitlement_Request" refreshTokenWhen="#[payload.error_description == &quot;Access Token Expired&quot;]">
            <oauth2:token-response accessToken="#[json:access_token]" expiresIn="#[json:expires_in]"/>
        </oauth2:token-request>
    </oauth2:client-credentials-grant-type>
</http:request-config>

<until-successful maxRetries="2" millisBetweenRetries="3000" synchronous="true" doc:name="Until Successful" failureExpression="#[message.inboundProperties['http.reason'] != &quot;Bad Request&quot;]">
    <http:request config-ref="HTTPS_Request_Configuration" path="${DATA.API.PATH}" method="PATCH" doc:name="HTTP">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:header headerName="Content-Type" value="application/json"/>
        </http:request-builder>
        <http:success-status-code-validator values="200..599"/>
    </http:request>
</until-successful>
```

Comment: Maybe the refreshTokenWhen. What happens if you log :#[payload.error_description == &quot;Access Token Expired&quot;] after the http call, to make sure that does evaluate to true.

Comment: Yes it's resolved to true, I validated that.